# How to get the (DOM/document) index of a clicked element in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the index of a clicked element using jquery - this should be easy with `.index()` but I don't want the index within a narrowly defined selector such as `$('div').index()`.

What I want is the unique index of that element on the page/in the DOM - something like `$(everything).index()` if it existed.

Here's my simple jquery click function:

```
$("div").click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   index = $(this).index();
});
```

Which I've used with some sample HTML:

```
<div>DIV 0 - I want to show as index=0 (which I do)</div>
<div>DIV 1 - I want to show as index=1 (which I do)</div>

<span>SPAN 0 - I want to show as (span) index=0</span>

<div>DIV 2 - I want to show as index=2 (but I don't, I show as 3)
    <div>DIV 3 - I want to show as index=3 (but I don't, I show as 0)</div>
    <span>SPAN 1 - I want to show as (span) index=1</span>
    <span>SPAN 2 - I want to show as (span) index=2</span>
</div>
```

I've [JSfiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/6n5zp/) about with it to play with.

My problems are these:

1) I don't know how to get a unique index number for these DIVS (or any other element for that matter) as `$(this)` only refers to the CURRENT selection, so embedded DIVs re-index at zero, once clicked.

2) I need this to work for ANY/ALL html tags (not just DIVs)

Thanks for any help you could give!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
$(document).on('click','*',function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var tag = this.tagName;
    var index = $(tag).index(this);  // it now works

    $('#output').html(index);
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/6n5zp/1/

Answer (score 4):

This works, although it probably isn't very efficient:

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   var others = document.getElementsByTagName(this.tagName);
   var index = [].indexOf.call(others, this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, the issue with this solution is I need it to work with ANY and ALL tag names, not just DIVs

Comment: this would improve in performance and resources a lot if you change `$('*').click(function(){..})` with `$(document).on('click','*',function(){..});`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli yes, I already did that.  My edit overlapped with your comment.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I suspect this version is likely quicker than your version using jQuery to create the element collection, too...

Comment: @Alnitak, 1. `divs` does not exist anymore in your code. 2. `others` should be the first argument and `this` the second. 3. In terms of speed it might be indeed the faster way, since it avoids the jquery overhead.. (*although it will most likely be doing the same thing behind the scenes*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli oops, typos caused by being drugged up to the eyeballs on anti-histamines.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using Alnitak solution, this will work for any element.

```
function getElementIndex(DOMELEMENT)
{
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(DOMELEMENT.tagName);
   return index = [].indexOf.call(elements , DOMELEMENT);
}
```